# Where do I put tests in an fsharp project using Monodevelop?

Tags: testing, f#, monodevelop

I am doing an assignment (implementing an algorithm), and I wanted to try, this time, implementing tests first. However, I simply do not know where to put them! Do I need to create a new project? 
All the tutorials I have found mentioned *what to write*, but not the general method of proceeding when building a test suite.

I expected Monodevelop to have some kind of predefined structure (like a big "add test suite" button), but I could not find anything for FSharp.

Monodevelop seems to have many tools to deal with tests in a clean and principled way (it does have a big "run tests" button), therefore I thought I would structure my project so that Monodevelop "sees" my tests, so that I could use the tools from the graphical interface. It seems the most common way to write tests is to use NUnit, what if I use something else, like FsCheck?

I have stumbled upon [a Github project called FSharpKoans](https://github.com/ChrisMarinos/FSharpKoans), it seems to suggest that I should create a project called "MySolution.Test" inside a solution, is this the standard way? 
What should be the type of the project then, is it a separate console application?

Thanks.

Comment: In professional software projects, where long-term maintainability is an issue, the most common approach is to [put tests in a separate library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2251005/126014).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, creating a separate "X.Test" project is the standard way of adding tests in .NET, F# is no exception here.

For testing framework, pick one that Monodevelop supports well if what you're looking for is IDE integration - NUnit sounds like a safe choice. You could conceivably use any framework in F# tests, so I would think what Monodevelop supports should dictate your choice here.

FsCheck is not a testing framework, it's a library for property-based testing that can be used in conjunction with any testing framework. You might want to look into it as it advocates a particularly interesting approach to testing, but it's by no means the only way or the required way of doing testing in F#.