# Can XUnit tests be run from within the project to be tested?

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

I'm wondering if it's possible to have xUnit tests in the same project as the source code is? 
I added the xUnit reference, but when I execute the tests, Visual Studio tells me that the project has no tests. I also tried to use `Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk`, but in that case an error was shown because the project had two entry points.

[image: Project explorer showing included packages]

```
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

> Implementation and better naming of the test will follow later...

Comment: Can you explain why you would like to have your tests in the same project? What benefits will you get by doing so? I'm asking because it's very unusual, like I never see anybody doing so.

Comment: How do you try to run the unit test?

Comment: @GuillaumeRaymond Like I said, I would like to know if it is possible. From other languages, I only know it to have them inside the same project.

Comment: @Chetan Yes, I tried to run it via VS context menu and via Dotnet-CLI.

Comment: Even if it's possible yo have xUnit tests in the same project as the source code , it is not a good practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250969/should-unit-tests-be-in-their-own-project-in-a-net-solution

Comment: Its not good practice to deploy binaries with test code, but it is good practice to require unit tests to pass before producing your production binaries. An unfortunate design decision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a console App with xUnit Test compiling is  a little bit tricky. One way to acheive this is to tweak the console App csproj.

Add the following statement in PropertyGroup section:

```
<GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
```

the final csproj should look like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
        <GenerateProgramFile>false</GenerateProgramFile>
    </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.3">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

For further reading on this subject please refer to this interesting  blog post by Andrew Lock : ["Program has more than one entry point defined" for console apps containing xUnit tests](https://andrewlock.net/fixing-the-error-program-has-more-than-one-entry-point-defined-for-console-apps-containing-xunit-tests/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can reproduce it, but in my case `CodeClass` will have a Main-Method and that is detected as second entry point for the program (CS0017). To adjust my question: Can you embed tests in console apps?

Comment: @tobias which version of .Net Framework are you using ?

Comment: I'm using .Net (Core) 5.0.

Comment: @tobias I've rewrite my answer because with a Console App there is a trick to make it compile